# Ansible Playbook Error: The powershell shell family is incompatible with the sudo become plugin

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible

I am working on a simple playbook that will ultimately be able to start/stop/restart windows services and I ran into an issue:

```
fatal: [mspdbwn1w01]: FAILED! => {
"msg": "The powershell shell family is incompatible with the sudo become plugin"
}
```

Below is the playbook:

```
- name: Add Host
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  strategy: linear

  tasks:
  - name: Add Temp Host
    add_host:
      name: "{{ win_client }}"
      group: temp
  - name: Target Server
    connection: winrm
    hosts: temp

    tasks:
      - name: Stop a service
        win_service:
        name: "{{ service }}"
        state: stopped
```

Google hasn't been much help, and I've tried everything I could find, every variation of become*.

I don't know if it matters, but due to the nature of the environment I work in, I have 2 separate users to log into *nix hosts vs. windows hosts.

Any assistance or guideance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One way or an other (in your inventory ? on your command line ?) your are asking ansible to perform [privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) (`become: true`) with a become plugin (`become_method: sudo`) which is not compatible with your shell. Side note: your example is not a valid playbook as it contains multiple yaml indentation errors. You should consider editing your question and fixing it.

Comment: I believe I fixed the formatting.  If it isn't, for the sake of the problem, assume it is?

I've tried become_method: runas wich become: true with no luck.

Comment: On windows be sure to include `become_method: runas` instead of sudo

Answer (score 5):

Your system seems to use `sudo` as the default become method, which is not compatible with PowerShell. For Windows (and PowerShell), you can use `runas` as the become method. Add:

```
become_method: runas
```

to your playbook or task. You can get a list of all available become methods with:

```
ansible-doc -t become -l
```

Example:

```
doas       Do As user
dzdo       Centrify's Direct Authorize
enable     Switch to elevated permissions on a network device
ksu        Kerberos substitute user
machinectl Systemd's machinectl privilege escalation
pbrun      PowerBroker run
pfexec     profile based execution
pmrun      Privilege Manager run
runas      Run As user
sesu       CA Privileged Access Manager
su         Substitute User
sudo       Substitute User DO
```

You can view the documentation for a particular become method with:

```
ansible-doc -t become runas
```

---

If you still get erros, pay attention to the error message, as it most probably is a different one. Using privilege escalation requires the definition of a username and a password for this purpose, for example.